# Why does var allow duplicate declaration but why does const and let not allow duplicate declaration?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, variables, var

### Why does var allow duplicate declaration but why does const and let not allow duplicate declaration?

`var` is allow duplicate declaration

```js
xx=1;
xx=2;
console.log(xx+xx);//4

var xx=1;
var xx=2;
console.log(xx+xx);//4
```

But `let` and `const` does not allow duplicate deceleration

```js
const yy=1;
const yy=2;
console.log(yy+yy);//Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'yy' has already been declared",

let zz=1;
let zz=2;
console.log(zz+zz);//Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'zz' has already been declared",
```

I saw something about that in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable) like,

> Assuming strict mode, `var` will let you re-declare the same variable in the same scope. On the other hand, `let` will not.

But I want to know Why `let` and `const` doesn't allow re-declaration? and why `var` does? and  How JavaScript handle these three type of deceleration ?

Comment: Why what? Why `let` doesn't allow redeclaration? Or why `var` does?

Comment: because `const` does what its name says, it is constant.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Let is scope sensitive, var isn't. I assume this choice was made to force js user to not fall into bad pratices.

Comment: var is an old thing. let and const where introduced so JS code is more strict with less unexpected behavior. If you try to redeclare it, it's not a normal behavior. Either you pick an other identifier, or you change the value (if it's not a const). Or you split your code into two functions because you have too much code lines in this one. It help thinking about your own code.

Comment: Please take a look at my question again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## var

The `var` keyword was the only way to define variables until 2016*.

No matter where you write `var x`, the variable `x` is treated as if it were declared at the top of the enclosing scope (scope for `var` is "a function").

All declarations of the variable *within the same scope* are effectively talking about the same variable.

Here is an example... you might think that within the function we overwrite the outer `name` with `fenton`, and add `Fenton` to the inner variable...

```
var name = 'Ramesh';

function myFunc() {
    name = 'fenton';

    var name = 'Fenton';

    alert(name);

}

myFunc();

alert(name);
```

In fact, it works just like this... the outer variable is not affected by the inner variable thanks to hoisting.

```
var name = 'Ramesh';

function myFunc() {
    var name;

    name = 'fenton';

    name = 'Fenton';

    alert(name);

}

myFunc();

alert(name);
```

- Actually, you could also declare them implicitly by not using the `var` keyword at all, in which case they would be added to the global scope. Subtle bugs were often tracked to this.

## let and const

Both `let` and `const` are block-scoped, not function-scoped. This makes them work like variables in most other C-like languages. It turns out this is just less confusing than function-scoped variables.

They are also both "more disciplined". They should be declared just once within a block.

The `const` keyword also disallows subsequent assignments - so you have to declare it with an assignment (i.e. you can't just write `const x`, you have to write `const x = 'Fenton'`) - and you can't assign another value later.

Some people think this makes the value immutable, but this is a mistake as the value can mutate, as shown below:

```
const x = [];

// I can mutate even though I can't re-assign
x.push('Fenton');

// x is now ['Fenton']
```

## Why Does it Matter?

If you want to avoid some of the more confusing aspects of `var`, such as multiple declarations all contributing to the same hoisted variable, and function-scope, you should use the newer `const` and `let` keywords.

I recommend using `const` as your default keyword, and upgrade it to `let` only in cases where you choose to allow re-assignment.

Comment: Such a long explanation. I am expecting to give a bounty to  this answer :) –

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `var`, `let` is an ES2015 specification. The [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) says:

> Redeclaring the same variable within the same function or block scope raises a SyntaxError.

This is to improve scoping over vanilla `var`.

Answer (score 2):

> why does const and let not allow duplicate declaration?

There's a big difference between how c# or java (for example) handle duplicate variable names, where name collision returns a compilation error, and how it works in an interpreted language like js. Please, check the snippet below: The value of `i` isn't duplicated? Not really, still, in the function and block context the same variable name is referred as two different variables, depending on where those are declared.

```js
function checkLetDuplication() {
  let i = 'function scope';
  for ( let i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )
  {
    console.log('(for statement scope): inside the for loop i, equals: ', i);
  }
  console.log('("checkLetDuplication" function scope): outside the for loop i , equals: ', i);
}
checkLetDuplication();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to know whether this behavior is as per spec, check this [13.3.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-variable-statement)

> Within the scope of any VariableEnvironment a common BindingIdentifier
>   **may appear in more than one VariableDeclaration** but those declarations
>   collective **define only one variable**.

`let` and `const` are the recent editions, while `var` is probably as old as Javascript itself.

In old days **Javascript code-base didn't used to be too big to bother about programming mistakes** and most probably focus was to ensure that **instead of reporting the error of re-declaration of variable JS engine should handle it**.