# Javascript: difference in execution of duplicate var and let variables within `execution context`?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, v8

I have recently noticed below code works

```
var x = 10;
var x = 20;
```

on the other side below throws error for redeclaration of same variable

```
let x = 10;
let x = 20;
```

Below link gives insights by keeping `functional scope` vs `block scope` as reference.

[Why does var allow duplicate declaration but why does const and let not allow duplicate declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148068/why-does-var-allow-duplicate-declaration-but-why-does-const-and-let-not-allow-du)

`var` declarations are executed in `execution context`, a entry in variableObject is created and re-declarations points to same entry/variable again and again in case of duplication.

How is this different in case of `let` ?

Isn't it still executed in `execution context` ?

Some good links or detailed explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there you can found an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148068/why-does-var-allow-duplicate-declaration-but-why-does-const-and-let-not-allow-du

Comment: Because that was a mistake from the beginning with `var` but it couldn't be changed for compatibility reasons. `let` and `const` are basically the fix for `var`.

Comment: @Lennholm yes, ideally `let` behaves in the correct manner but not `var`. I agree with you on this. Still more interested in how engines sees it and differentiates in execution of both.

Comment: It's because var is function scoped and let is block scoped,, so a variable declared with var is defined throughout the program while let not.

Comment: @JaspreetSingh The specification dictates it that way. Are you asking why JS engines adhere to the specification or how engines implement it internally?

Comment: @Lennholm I guess question was marked duplicate even before I could edit it, could you have a look at it now ?